# XSD for XML where the main elements can be anywhere in the structure, and the occurrence of their sub-elements based on the condition

Tags: xml, xsd

I am totally lost.

This is what I want:

This is XML1:

```
 <EL0 attr0="type1">
   <EL1 attr1="someValue"/>
   <EL2>
    <EL2_SUBEL1>String1</EL2_SUBEL1>
    <EL2_SUBEL2 attr2="value1"/>
   </EL2>
 <EL0>
```

This is XML2:

```
 <EL0 attr0="type2">
   <EL1 attr1="someValue"/>
   <EL2>
    <EL2_SUBEL3>String1</EL2_SUBEL3>
   </EL2>
   <EL3 attr4="value2"/>
 <EL0>
```

Elements are:

1. Root element: EL0
2. Elements, which can be anywhere in the structure (in the future but now in the root):

a) El1 with the attribute "attr0"

b) EL2

c) El3 with the attribute "attr4"

EL2 has 3 elements, but based on EL0 attr0 value ("type1" and "type2"):

```
<EL2_SUBEL1>String1</EL2_SUBEL1>
<EL2_SUBEL2 attr2="value1"/>
<EL2_SUBEL3>String2</EL2_SUBEL3>
```

1. if EL0 attr0 value is "type1" then sub-elements of EL2 are EL2_SUBEL1 and EL2_SUBEL2
2. if EL0 attr0 value is "type2" then sub-elements of EL2 is EL2_SUBEL3

This is what I did but there are some errors.

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 
   <!-- Define complex type for EL1 -->
   <xs:complexType name="EL1Type">
     <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:complexType>
      
   <!-- Define complex type for EL2_SUBEL1 -->
   <xs:complexType name="EL2_SUBEL1Type">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="EL2_SUBEL1" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 
   <!-- Define complex type for EL2_SUBEL2 -->
   <xs:complexType name="EL2_SUBEL2Type">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="EL2_SUBEL2">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 
   <!-- Define complex type for EL2_SUBEL3 -->
   <xs:complexType name="EL2_SUBEL3Type">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="EL2_SUBEL3" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 
   <!-- Define complex type for EL3 -->
   <xs:complexType name="EL3Type">
     <xs:simpleContent>
       <xs:extension base="xs:string">
         <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
 
   <!-- Define complex type for EL3 for "type1" -->
   <xs:complexType name="type1">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 
   <!-- Define complex type for EL3 for "type2" -->
   <xs:complexType name="type2">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 
   <!-- Define the root element "EL0" -->
   <xs:element name="EL0">
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="EL1" type="EL1Type"/>
         <xs:element name="EL3">
           <xs:complexType>
             <xs:choice>
               <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
               <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
               <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
             </xs:choice>
           </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="EL3" type="EL3Type"/>
       </xs:sequence>
       <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
 
 </xs:schema>
```

But, of course, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of constraint:

```
if EL0 attr0 value is "type1" 
   then sub-elements of EL2 are EL2_SUBEL1 and EL2_SUBEL2
if EL0 attr0 value is "type2" 
   then sub-elements of EL2 is EL2_SUBEL3
```

You need XSD 1.1. This is an exact fit for the feature "Conditional Type Assignment" which makes the complex type of an element conditional on the value of its attributes.

There are a number of schema processors that support XSD 1.1 but many only support 1.0. If you can't use a 1.1 processor, then you can't define these constraints, so you will have to supplement the XSD validation with some other processing, for example using Schematron or a custom XSLT validation phase.

Comment: thank you for this info :) but what should XSD look like? I am lost and stuck...btw, XSD 1.1 has been there for a long time, I remember that you can also provide multiple outputs (like multiple files)...or it is 2.0?

Comment: Sorry, I'm happy to point people in the right direction, but not to hold their hands and walk them all the way to their destination. In your comments about XSD 1.1, I think you're confusing it with XSLT 2.0. You need to do some reading.

Comment: I know, usually, I appreciate that but here I have a lot of other tasks to do and here I am just stuck, an infinite loop in my head, thnx. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional type assignment https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative, a possible (there is some confusion in your sample XML and schemas as to whether the attribute defining the type is `attr0` or `type`, I went with `type`, the other attribute names also seem to be different in the schema and the samples) schema would be e.g.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 
   <xs:element name="EL1">
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:simpleContent>
         <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="attr1" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:extension>
       </xs:simpleContent>
     </xs:complexType>     
   </xs:element>
   
   <xs:element name="EL2_SUBEL1" type="xs:string"/>

   <xs:element name="EL2_SUBEL2">
     <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="attr2" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:complexType>     
   </xs:element> 
   
  <xs:element name="EL2_SUBEL3" type="xs:string"/>
  
  <xs:element name="EL3">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:simpleContent>
       <xs:extension base="xs:string">
         <xs:attribute name="attr4" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 
   <!-- Define the root element "EL0" -->
   <xs:element name="EL0">
     <xs:alternative test="@type = 'type1'" type="Type1"/>
     <xs:alternative test="@type = 'type2'" type="Type2"/>
     <xs:alternative type="xs:error"/>
   </xs:element>
   
   <xs:complexType name="Type1">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="EL1"/>
       <xs:element name="EL2">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL1"/>
             <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL2"/>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:complexType name="Type2">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="EL1"/>
       <xs:element name="EL2">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element ref="EL2_SUBEL3"/>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
       <xs:element ref="EL3"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Two valid XML instances are e.g.

```
<EL0 type="type1">
   <EL1 attr1="someValue"/>
   <EL2>
    <EL2_SUBEL1>String1</EL2_SUBEL1>
    <EL2_SUBEL2 attr2="value1"/>
   </EL2>
</EL0>
```

and

```
<EL0 type="type2">
   <EL1 attr1="someValue"/>
   <EL2>
    <EL2_SUBEL3>String1</EL2_SUBEL3>
   </EL2>
   <EL3 attr4="value2"/>
</EL0>
```

As for XSD 1.1 support, Apache Java Xerces (https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/xml-schema.html) offers that, as does the Python xmlschema library https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/, as does Saxon EE (requires a commercial license) for Java and .NET.

Comment: Thnx once more. Tell me, will this work with org.codehaus.mojo / jaxb2-maven-plugin / 3.1.0? I need maven dependency to create classes from XSD.

Comment: I don't know whether JAXB has been updated to support XSD 1.1 based class generation. As for the XSD 1.1 version of Apache Xerces on Maven, Adam Retter has an article about that at https://blog.adamretter.org.uk/xerces-xsd11-maven/.

Comment: Is it possible to trick this behaviour in XSD 1.0? For example, to have like: <type1:EL0><EL1 attr1="someValue"/><EL2><EL2_SUBEL1>String1</EL2_SUBEL1><EL2_SUBEL2 attr2="value1"/></EL2></type1:EL0>  and  <type2:EL0><EL1 attr1="someValue"/><EL2><EL2_SUBEL3>String1</EL2_SUBEL3></EL2><EL3 attr4="value2"/></type2:EL0> ? JAXB would create 2 classes or?